# How to get a specific string from sentences

Tags: ruby

What is the best method in Rails to get a specific string from a sentence?

For example, I have:

```
"My working time is: 3 hours and the job is finished"
"Bla2 time is: 6 hours and the job is still pending"
"Bla bla bla time is: 7 hours and the job is finished"
```

I want to take the number after the words `"time is: "`, so the expected output is only the numbers like: `3`, `6`, `7`.

Comment: I'd do it with [regular expressions](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)". We need to see your effort toward solving this. Currently it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the code for you, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex: [Rubular for testing regex](https://rubular.com/).

For your particular case you can do this:

```
"My working time is: 3 hours and the job finished at 4".match(/time is: (\d+)/)[1]
```

Which returns:

```
"3"
```

Or:

```
"My working time is: 3 hours and the job finished at 4".scan(/time is: (\d+)/).first
```

Which returns:

```
["3"]
```

Comment: Your expression doesn't fit case when there is more than 9 hours, so it will match only first digit. I suggest to use `match(/\d+/)` instead

Comment: but the sentences output is dynamic, so we can't take exactly the specific number

Comment: @MuhammadJafar It's not taking into consideration specific number but any number that will be present in the sentence. You should read the link shared in the question comments.

Comment: okay but the problem is your regex is only to detect any digits, what if the sentences is like this "Current time: 15.42 and My working time is: 3 hours"
i need to detect the digits after words "time is: " from this example

Comment: so the outcome of number will be only specific after specific words

Comment: Edited the answer as per your comments, now it will only detect digits are the word `time is: " `

Comment: The pattern is still unnecessarily complex. `/time is: (\d+)/` is sufficient. Anything beyond that wastes the regular expression engine's CPU time trying to match `.*`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are trying to get working hours of people from each sentence.

```
sentences = ["My working time is: 3 hours and the job is finished", "Bla2 working time is: 6 hours and the job is still pending", "Bla bla bla working time is: 7 hours and the job is finished"]

sentences.each_with_object({}) do |sentence, person_working_time|
  person, time = sentence.match(/(.*) working time is: (\d+)/)[1,2]
  person_working_time[person] = time
end

# Output: { "My" => "3", "Bla2" => "6", "Bla bla bla" => "7" }
```

Comment: okay this is the most satisfying for me, i will try first
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this regular expression:

```
str = "My working time is: 12 hours and the job is finished"

match = str.match(%r{.* time is: (\d+).*})
match[1] => "12"
```

So it will find `time is:` in string and capture all digits right after this phrase but not the other digits if any exist.

Comment: Anchoring to `\A` seems to be meaningless, if you follow it with a `.*`

Comment: Consider `str[%r{ time is: (\d+)}, 1] #=> "12"` (See the penultimate form of [String#\[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)). Note that `.*` has no effect when at the beginning or end of a regular expression.

Comment: Unless the regex engine optimizes out `.*` at the start and end of the pattern it's actually slowing the processing. Benchmarks will probably show whether that's the case, and I'd _hope_ that it does.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with:

```
strings = [
  "My working time is: 3 hours and the job is finished",
  "Bla2 time is: 6 hours and the job is still pending",
  "Bla bla bla time is: 7 hours and the job is finished"
]
```

If all you want is the digits for the time, only grab the digits immediately before "`hours`":

```
hours = strings.map { |s| s[/(\d+) hours/, 1] }
# => ["3", "6", "7"]
```

If you want each value as an integer:

```
hours = strings.map { |s| s[/(\d+) hours/, 1].to_i }
# => [3, 6, 7]
```

This takes advantage of String's [`[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method which takes a pattern and the index of possible captures, among other things:

> `str[regexp, capture] → new_str or nil`
>
> :
>
> If a `Regexp` is supplied, the matching portion of the string is returned. If a `capture` follows the regular expression, which may be a capture group index or name, follows the regular expression that component of the MatchData is returned instead.

Alternately, the pattern could just as easily key off the preceding colon:

```
hours = strings.map { |s| s[/: (\d+)/, 1] }
# => ["3", "6", "7"]
```

and:

```
hours = strings.map { |s| s[/: (\d+)/, 1].to_i }
# => [3, 6, 7]
```

It's not necessary to use wildcards, just find a landmark in the string and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, a string (sentence) can have more than one number included. This would catch all of them:

```
str = "My working time is: 12 hours, but the job was already finished after 11"
str.scan(/[0-9]+/)
# => ["12","11"]
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Comment: @gehbiszumeis : Explanation added. I thought the code allown would be obvious, as the context is so simple; do you think it's complete and understandable now?